# how to call php page with 3 arguments from powershell

Tags: php, powershell, arguments

below is my PS1 code to call PHP. But I want to know how to call the PHP page with 3 arguments and how to get it in PHP.

```
$workflow_id = 170
$task_num = 3
$next_script = 'testing.php'
$PhpExe  = "C:\Admin\bin\php\php7.4.26\php.exe"
$PhpFile = "C:\Admin\www\xpress\"+$next_script+" "+$workflow_id+" "+$task_num
echo $PhpFile
$PhpArgs = '-f "{0}"' -f $PhpFile
$PhpOutput = & $PhpExe $PhpArgs 
echo $PhpOutput // could not open file. but the file is present in this path
```

// testing.php

```
<?php include("commons/connection.php"); ?>
<?php
$workflow_id = $argv[1];
$task_num = $argv[2];    
$update_pass = "UPDATE workflow_details SET Status ='mm' where `Workflow_Number` = $workflow_id and Work_type = 'PrepWork' and Task_Number =  $task_num " ; 
$status_result=mysqli_query($con,$update_pass);
    ?>
```

I am getting could not open file. while running ps1

Comment: Do the descriptions and examples here help at all? https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php If not, could you [edit] your question to explain exactly where you're stuck?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the arguments in on the command line? Or how to read them in PHP? Either way, the manual should be your starting point, and it's not difficult to google it either

Comment: To properly call `php.exe`, use something like `$PhpOutput = & $PhpExe -f $PhpFile`

Comment: @ADyson I have edited my question. I googled it i am getting php to powershell but not vise versa.

Comment: @IMSoP  I have edited my question . hope you will understand now.

Comment: Passing the args is just a case of generating a string in powershell like `php myscript.php value1 value2`. And reading them is easy, they're in `$argv` in PHP. That's all explained in the documentation or from googling other examples. So again where _exactly_ are you stuck with implementing that process? Perhaps your powershell isn't creating a valid command string or something? Be more specific about the issue.

Comment: @ADyson As you told while running this PS script , it not calling PHP page and while printing $PhpOutput its throwing Could not open input file

Comment: @ADyson I have edited please see and give your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to call your PHP script from PowerShell is flawed in two respects:

- `$PhpArgs` is a *single* string, which is therefore passed as a *single* argument, whereas you need to pass `-f` and the PHP script file name/path as *individual* arguments.
- You're not passing any arguments to pass through to the PHP script.

Therefore, invoke `$PhpExe` as follows:

```bash
# Call script file $PhpFile with the values of $workflow_id and $task_num
# as arguments, and capture the output in variable $PhpOutput
$PhpOutput = & $PhpExe -f $PhpFile -- $workflow_id $task_num
```